# How to make a MongoDB index with using a variable in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using `createIndex()` in MongoDB in Node.js. I was wondering how I could insert a variable into `createIndex`.

For instance I have `var x = "insert"`. I would like to make an index called "insert" by using `x`. I have tried `createIndex({x:1})` but all this does is make `x` the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In es6

```
createIndex({[x]:1})
```

In es5

```
var indexQuery = {};
indexQuery[x] = 1;
createIndex(indexQuery);
```

Comment: Thank you forgot the exact syntax your a life saver.